# QNetworkAccessManager doesn't work properly after link down/link up

Tags: c++, qt, embedded

My client on embedded device uses QNetworkAccessManager to communicate with our backend server. When I remove patching cord from device on long time then after  inserting it back my QNetworkAccessManager object doesn't work properly. After posting data on server it returns error "host not found". Removing patching cord from router doesn't produce such error. Also this behavior is observed on some kind devices but for PC or other type of embedded devices all are Ok.

**On device where all are OK I use
target = sh4
Linux 2.6.32.59 qt 4.7.2
On device with error: Linux 
2.6.32.59-b2067, qt 4.8.4**

Below is code where QNetworkAccessManager is used:

```
void CmdUrlRequest::execute()
{
        static QNetworkAccessManager n_manager;
#if QT_VERSION>=0x040700
        if(QUrl(*_url).host()=="localhost" || QUrl(*_url).host().right(3)=="zet")
            QNetworkProxyFactory::setUseSystemConfiguration(false);
        else
            QNetworkProxyFactory::setUseSystemConfiguration(true);
#endif
    if (_timeout_tm==NULL)  
    {
        _timeout_tm=new QTimer(this);
        _timeout_tm->setInterval(_timeout);
        _timeout_tm->setSingleShot(true);
        connect(_timeout_tm, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timeoutedDxprequest()));
    }
    qDebug() << "CmdUrlRequest::execute" << "command ID" << _command_id << "URL execute()" << this << *_url << QThread::currentThread();

    assert(n_manager.thread()->currentThreadId()==_timeout_tm->thread()->currentThreadId());

    if (_url && _method)
    {
        QString b;
        if (_body)
            b=*_body;

        _array_ptr->clear();
        _manager = &n_manager;// new QNetworkAccessManager();
        _manager->setCookieJar(StoredCookieJar::Instance());
        StoredCookieJar::Instance()->setParent(0);
        _nreq = QNetworkRequest();
        _nreq.setUrl(QUrl(*_url));


        if ((*_url).startsWith("https"))
        {           
            QSslConfiguration sslc;
            sslc.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
            sslc.setProtocol(QSsl::AnyProtocol);
            _nreq.setSslConfiguration(sslc);
        }
        if(*_method != "get")
        {
            _nreq.setRawHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            _nreq.setRawHeader("Authorization","Basic YXJlczpGWGEwc2tsNGQ=");
        }

        QList<QPair<QByteArray,QByteArray> >::iterator hid;

        if(_headers!=NULL)
            for(hid=_headers->begin(); hid!=_headers->end(); ++hid)
            {
                _nreq.setRawHeader(hid -> first, hid -> second);
                qDebug() << this -> metaObject() -> className() << hid -> first << hid -> second;
            }
        _post_data=_body->toUtf8();
        qDebug() << this -> metaObject() -> className() << "method =" << *_method << _body->toUtf8();

        _req_timeresp = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toTime_t();

        if(*_method == "post")
            _nres = _manager -> post(_nreq, _post_data);
        else if(*_method == "head")
            _nres = _manager -> head(_nreq);
        else if(*_method == "get")
            _nres = _manager -> get(_nreq);
        qDebug() << this -> metaObject() -> className() << "res =" << _nres ;
        connect(_nres, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(getResponse()));
        connect(_nres, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this, SLOT(progress(qint64,qint64)));
        connect(_nres, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
        connect(_nres, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)), this, SLOT(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));

        _timeout_tm->start();
    }
    else
    {
        onResult(CMD_ERROR);
    }

}
```

Comment: IMHO; The Qt network classes could use some work. You are not the first to find bugs there - Qt 5 is a little better, but could still use some work.

Comment: Linux 2.6.32?? That's *ancient*.. why don't you use a modern kernel?

Comment: It doen't depend from me. Vendor of stb boxes produces for as rootfs etc...

Comment: On other device I have different result - cpu overhead every 20 seconds. I found that in this case I have socket in state CLOSE_WAIT(vapp    2210 root   45u  IPv4 2730200      0t0  TCP imaqliqtv->someserver:www (CLOSE_WAIT)

Comment: For the interactive webapps on Linux when hard reboots and cable disconnects are frequent, a good option to set is the `net.ipv4.tcp_thin_linear_timeouts` (2.6.34 though) - active connections don't stuck for a long time when devices are disconnected.

Comment: Unfortunately my kernel doesn't support this option.